# Dihedral Group generated by reflection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Good evening,

I need some help, with the following task.
I know that there are two reflections $t,t'$ with $\langle t, t' \rangle = D_n$.

Now I should tell what I can say generally for two reflections $t,t' \in D_n$ with $t \neq t'$.
I know that sometimes the two reflections generate the whole group $D_n$.

But if I look at $D_8=\{id,r,...,r^7,s,sr,...,sr^7\}$ with s=reflection r=rotation then it is not possible to generate every rotation with the two reflections $sr^2$ and $sr^4$. I can't generate $r^7$ for example. I only can generate rotations with an even exponent. If I take $D_3$ then it is possible to generate every element with two reflections, but why?

I read that I can generate dihedral groups $D_m$ with $m|n$. Maybe you can help me to understand that

Comment: If you have $sr^i$ and $sr^j$, $i\neq j$, then you can generate $\langle r^k\rangle$ with $k=\gcd(i,j,n)$. When $n=3$, any distinct $i$ and $j$ will do. When $n=8$, you need at least one of $i$ and $j$ to be odd.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can generate every dihedral group when at least one of $i$ and $j$ is odd? Or is it important that the gcd is $1$

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $sr^3$ and $sr^6$ do **not** generate the dihedral group of order $18$ ($n=9$ with your notation). And neither do $sr^3$ and $sr^9$ for $n=12$. So, no; it’s not enough for one of them to be odd. If the powers of $r$ you have generate a proper subgroup of $\langle r\rangle$, there’s no way you can get all of $D_n$.

Comment: Oops; wait. $sr$ and $sr^3$ generate the proper subgroup of order $4$ given by $\{e, sr, r^2, sr^3\}$ in $D_4$. You don’t get the whole subgroup. My first comment is incorrect. The subgroup of rotations you get is *contained* in the subgroup generated by $r^k$, but it not necessarily equal to it.